# A function that calculate the total cost of each order from a dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that represent orders in an online store. Each dictionary contains keys for the order ID, customer ID, and a list of line items, where each line item is itself a dictionary containing keys for the product ID, quantity, and price

```
orders = [    
    {'order_id': 1, 'customer_id': 1001, 'line_items': [
        {'product_id': 'A001', 'quantity': 2, 'price': 10.00},
        {'product_id': 'B002', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 5.00},
        {'product_id': 'C003', 'quantity': 3, 'price': 2.50},
    ]},
    {'order_id': 2, 'customer_id': 1002, 'line_items': [
        {'product_id': 'D004', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 20.00},
        {'product_id': 'E005', 'quantity': 2, 'price': 15.00},
    ]},
    {'order_id': 3, 'customer_id': 1003, 'line_items': [
        {'product_id': 'F006', 'quantity': 4, 'price': 3.00},
        {'product_id': 'G007', 'quantity': 2, 'price': 5.00},
        {'product_id': 'H008', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 8.00},
    ]},
    {'order_id': 4, 'customer_id': 1004, 'line_items': [
        {'product_id': 'F006', 'quantity': 4, 'price': 3.00},
        {'product_id': 'G007', 'quantity': 2, 'price': 5.00},
        {'product_id': 'H008', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 8.00},
    ]},
    {'order_id': 5, 'customer_id': 1005, 'line_items': [
        {'product_id': 'F006', 'quantity': 4, 'price': 3.00},
        {'product_id': 'G007', 'quantity': 2, 'price': 5.00},
        {'product_id': 'H008', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 8.00},
    ]},
]
```

I want to calculate the total cost of each order and add it as a new key to each dictionary. You also want to add a new key called customer_name that contains the name of the customer associated with each order, which you can look up in a separate list of dictionaries that maps customer IDs to names (taking into consideration i don't have all the customers name):

```
customers = [{'customer_id': 1001, 'name': 'Alice'},
             {'customer_id': 1002, 'name': 'Bob'},
             {'customer_id': 1003, 'name': 'Charlie'},
             {'customer_id': 1004, 'name': 'jack'}]
```

I tried thisn but it didnt work

```
for order in orders:
    for customer in customers:
        if order['customer_id'] == customer['customer_id']:
            print('Order id: ' + str(order['order_id']))
            print('Customer name: ' + customer['name'])
            total_price = 0
            for line_item in order['line_items']:
                total_price = line_item['quantity'] * line_item['price']
            print(total_price)
            print('-----------------------')
```

I am looking for something to return, something like  `'total_cost': 32.5, 'customer_name': 'Alice'}`, at the end of the order of the customer Alice

Comment: Try doing it manually, writing down step-by-step how you do it, then this becomes the pseudo-code you can use to help write your python code. Also, please try and only ask 1 question in a question on Stack Overflow - you've got two separate questions here. Finally, please show us the loops you've tried that don't work. Good luck!

Comment: _I tried a couple of loops here and there, but nothing works_ If you don't show us what you tried, we can't point out what you did wrong.

Comment: Why not use pandas and format your data as rows and columns with suitable indices. It's simpler than these multiple nested dictionaries and is much better for accessing and viewing the data in different ways.

Comment: since dictionary is an iterable object, try to map() on each item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a customer_map dictionary to map customer IDs to names. Then, I loop through the orders list to calculate the total cost of each order using `map()` and a lambda function. I add the total_cost and customer_name keys to each order dictionary, by looking up the customer name in the customer_map using the customer_id key.

```
customer_map = {customer['customer_id']: customer['name'] for customer in customers}
for order in orders:
    line_items = order['line_items']
    total_cost = sum(map(lambda item: item['quantity'] * item['price'], line_items))
    order['total_cost'] = total_cost
    customer_id = order['customer_id']
    # i get a KeyError when trying to look up the name of customer ID 1005 in the customer_map
    # but this should do
    if customer_id in customer_map:
        order['customer_name'] = customer_map[customer_id]
    else:
        order['customer_name'] = 'Unknown'

# note that i relocate the output in the same variable( i hope this is what you want )
print(orders)

# return

# orders = [
#     {'order_id': 1, 'customer_id': 1001, 'line_items': 
#      [{'product_id': 'A001', 'quantity': 2, 'price': 10.0},
#        {'product_id': 'B002', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 5.0}, 
#        {'product_id': 'C003', 'quantity': 3, 'price': 2.5}], 'total_cost': 32.5, 'customer_name': 'Alice'}, 
#     {'order_id': 2, 'customer_id': 1002, 'line_items': 
#      [{'product_id': 'D004', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 20.0}, 
#       {'product_id': 'E005', 'quantity': 2, 'price': 15.0}], 'total_cost': 50.0, 'customer_name': 'Bob'}, 
#     {'order_id': 3, 'customer_id': 1003, 'line_items':
#       [{'product_id': 'F006', 'quantity': 4, 'price': 3.0}, 
#        {'product_id': 'G007', 'quantity': 2, 'price': 5.0}, 
#        {'product_id': 'H008', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 8.0}], 'total_cost': 30.0, 'customer_name': 'Charlie'}, 
#     {'order_id': 4, 'customer_id': 1004, 'line_items': 
#      [{'product_id': 'F006', 'quantity': 4, 'price': 3.0}, 
#       {'product_id': 'G007', 'quantity': 2, 'price': 5.0}, 
#       {'product_id': 'H008', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 8.0}], 'total_cost': 30.0, 'customer_name': 'jack'}, 
#     {'order_id': 5, 'customer_id': 1005, 'line_items': 
#     [{'product_id': 'F006', 'quantity': 4, 'price': 3.0}, 
#      {'product_id': 'G007', 'quantity': 2, 'price': 5.0}, 
#      {'product_id': 'H008', 'quantity': 1, 'price': 8.0}], 'total_cost': 30.0, 'customer_name': 'Unknown'}]
```

You can read about [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), [lambda](https://realpython.com/python-lambda/)